# Getting first row of non-index internal tables

Tags: abap

I have a variable with type of ANY TABLE, and it should be, as it could contain STANDARD, SORTED, or HASHED, and I need to get the first line of that table.

Using index access such as

```
READ TABLE itab INDEX 1` or `itab[ 1 ]
```

is not possible with that type. Is there an elegant way to get the first line?

My way isn't elegant:

```
LOOP AT itab ASSIGNING <ls_line>.
  EXIT.
ENDLOOP.
```

Googling found [similar question](https://answers.sap.com/questions/10141977/last-row-content-in-an-hashed-table.html) without appropriate answer.

Comment: A hashed table is not indexed, however SAP permitted to loop at entries of hashed tables ["in the order in which they were inserted in the table, and by the sort order used after the statement SORT \[if any\]"](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abaploop_at_itab.htm)). Maybe your solution is not elegant but it's the shortest and clearest code when the internal table is hashed or of type any table...

Comment: By the way, as I said, reading the "first" line of a hashed internal table means reading the first line inserted, it's a little bit like reading "any" line of the internal table because there's no functional meaning of reading the "first" line. What is the goal? (NB: if you have used SORT, then prefer adding a secondary sorted key to the hashed internal table and access its first line via this key).

Comment: indeed, any row would be fine. asked for first one for simplifying. the goal is to get some info which is same in any row. then make a decision if need to iterate.

Answer (score 1):

Your question has no sense, since you cannot unambiguously define what is *first* in your task.

Your generic variable can accept any table. If this is hashed table, then it is organized **by key fields**, most often it resembles database table, if DB-table has the same key.

If this is index tables (standard or sorted), then its sort order is determined **by index**, which has nothing to do with fields order or key. If some manipulation were done with table (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) it will be different from natural sort and DB sort.

Answer (score 1):

The meaning of the "first line" of a hashed internal table is a little bit subjective, as a hashed internal table is usually to be accessed with a key value, not a position.

If you mean the first line "[in the order in which [the lines] were inserted in the table, and by the sort order used after the statement SORT [if any]](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abaploop_at_itab.htm)", there's no solution better than the one proposed in the question:

```
TYPES ty_hashed_table TYPE HASHED TABLE OF string WITH UNIQUE KEY table_line.
DATA(hashed_table) = VALUE ty_hashed_table( ( `World` ) ( `Hello` ) ).
LOOP AT hashed_table ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<line>).
  EXIT.
ENDLOOP.
ASSERT <line> = `World`.
```

If "first line" means the line with a given component of the hashed internal table containing the lowest value, you may define a secondary **sorted** key:

```
TYPES ty_hashed_table TYPE HASHED TABLE OF string WITH UNIQUE KEY table_line
                      WITH NON-UNIQUE SORTED KEY by_table_line COMPONENTS table_line
                      ##TABKEY[PRIMARY_KEY][BY_TABLE_LINE].
DATA(hashed_table) = VALUE ty_hashed_table( ( `World` ) ( `Hello` ) ).
ASSIGN hashed_table[ KEY by_table_line INDEX 1 ] TO FIELD-SYMBOL(<line>).
ASSERT <line> = `Hello`.
```

Answer (score -1):

For anyone that finds this post, there are 2 ways to get the first row.
First is doing a select in your table but only reading 1 row.

```
SELECT * FROM your_internal_table UP TO 1 ROWS INTO your_work_area.
  " your logic here
ENDSELECT.
```

The other way around is simply using READ and selecting the first index

```
READ TABLE your_internal_table INTO your_work_area INDEX 1.
" your logic here
```

That is pretty much it.
The second solution will help you out if you are managing the internal table as a hash table. Though there are more elegant ways to do so. You can view this two options as knowing that you will always have 1 row but do not want to use loops to extract it.